# Find an ancestor with a particular class. Selenium. WebDriver. Using XPath

Tags: java, selenium, testing, ancestor

I am trying to find an XPath query to get an ancestor of my element, which is a `div` with a `class='row publication-detail teaser'`.

What I am currently doing is the following :

```
element.findElements(By.xpath("//ancestor::div[@class='row publication-detail teaser']"));
```

The problem is, it is returning all the siblings of `div[@class='row publication-detail teaser']`. And I only need the one that's my elements ancestor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess I found the first issue: I should have started with `./` relative path, i think it starts looking everywhere when you start with `//`. That didn't solve my problem completely. 
For those who might be itesrted in the topic - i found a cool cheat sheet:  https://devhints.io/xpath

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct, but `findElements` will give you list of elements instead use `findElement`

try replacing your **code** like this :

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("your web element here from where you want to go to ancestor, then use ancestor like this //ancestor::div[@class='row publication-detail teaser']"));
```